# php curl CURLOPT_HTTPGET doesn't set method back to GET

Tags: php, curl

In my code, I am reusing the same connection to do multiple calls, some GET, POST or PUT. 
After a PUT, I do want to do a GET, but it still keep the old "PUT" method.
Sample of my code:

1st call:

```
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($jiraput));
$response = curl_exec($this->jira);
```

2nd call:

```
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$response = curl_exec($this->jira);
```

Verbose logs give me:

```
* Found bundle for host domain.com: 0x227b490
* Re-using existing connection! (#3) with host domain.com
* Connected to url.domain.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#3)
> PUT /jira/rest/api/2/issue/DAM-188/editmeta HTTP/1.1
```

As a workaround, I have modified the 2nd call:

```
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
$response = curl_exec($this->jira);
```

but still, it doesn't make sense, CURLOPT_HTTPGET should have done the trick.

Comment: Setting `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` to true won't reset `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` content. I suppose you can just set it to an empty string and set HTTPGET to true.

Answer (score 0):

libcurl/curl saves the state of properties you changed.
Just add this before the GET request, or after the POST:

```
curl_setopt($this->jira, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, NULL);
```